# Switching between two CSS files for a Page in Wrodpress

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to convert my html template to a WordPress theme. The html template has a switch to convert the theme of the page between 'Light' and 'Dark' (I have a CSS file for both light and dark mode so basically I used JavaScript to switch between those two files on button click).

Now I am trying to convert my template to a WordPress theme and the problem I am facing is that when I add the CSS files to the functions.php it seems to load all CSS files at once. Is there a way in WordPress I could switch between these files on a button click.

Here is the functions.php file

```
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

  function load_stylesheets(){

      wp_register_style('homepage', get_template_directory_uri() . '/CSS/homepage.css', array(), 1, 'all');
      wp_enqueue_style('homepage');

      wp_register_style('homepage', get_template_directory_uri() . '/CSS/homepage_dark.css', array(), 1, 'all');
      wp_enqueue_style('homepage_dark');

      wp_register_style('single', get_template_directory_uri() . '/CSS/single.css', array(), 1, 'all');
      wp_enqueue_style('single');

  }

  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');
  

// Load Scripts

function load_js(){
  
  wp_register_script('homepagejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/JavaScript/homepage.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
  wp_enqueue_script('homepagejs'); 

  wp_register_script('masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
  wp_enqueue_script('masonry');

  wp_register_script('singlejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/JavaScript/single.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
  wp_enqueue_script('singlejs'); 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');

?>
```

Here is the JS file with toggle function

```
window.onload = () =>{
    const grid = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
    const masonry = new Masonry(grid, {
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        gutter: 15,
        marginBottom: 15,
        columnWidth: 260,
        fitWidth: true,
        horizontalOrder: true

    });
}



function toggleTheme() {
    // Obtains an array of all <link>
    // elements.
    // Select your element using indexing.
    var theme = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("switch")
    // Change the value of href attribute 
    // to change the css sheet.
    if (theme.getAttribute('href') == '/CSS/homepage.css') {
        theme.setAttribute('href', '/CSS/homepage_dark.css');
        btn.value = "Light Mode"
        document.getElementsByClassName('img_logo').src= '/assets/img/logo_white.svg'
    } else {
        theme.setAttribute('href', '/CSS/homepage.css');
        btn.value = "Dark Mode"
        document.getElementsByClassName('img_logo').src= '/assets/img/logo.svg'
    }
}
```

Changing the theme onchange in front-page.php

```
 <div class ="dark_mode_switch">
     <label class="switch" id="theme_toggle_switch" onchange="toggleTheme()">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
     </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: You really should add any code you have tried to make this work so the community can see that you have a made an effort at trying to resolve this on your own. Questions that show no effort at trying to resolve their issues will surely get closed.

Comment: I added the code I am using.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to take the CSS style-sheet URLs and output them to in-line JavaScript.

So in your functions.php you could do somthing like this:

```php
function load_js() {
    $stylesheets = [
        'themes' => [
            'dark' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/CSS/homepage_dark.css',
            'light' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/CSS/homepage.css' 
        ]
    ];

    wp_register_script('singlejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/JavaScript/single.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_add_inline_script( 'singlejs', json_encode($stylesheets));
}
```

Then you can amend your JavaScript to grab the style-sheet URLs and do whatever you want with them:

```js
console.log(themes.light);
console.log(themes.dark);
```